# Video streaming-Error

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

My code for a simple video streaming web page is given below. On Firefox the error that it gives is:

**No video with supported format and MIME type found**

The code is:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zY1vLEk8B9c" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

On trying it with chrome the play button does not turn up.

I am new to web development and do not know where I am going wrong. What should I do to get the video running?

Comment: [Firefox might not support MP4 on some platform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4), and...I think your URL does not point to a valid video source, just a web page.

Comment: @Passerby the video is League of Legends trailer on youtube. Why is it not valid? And then what about the error on Chrome?

Comment: Chrome doesn't show a play button because your `src` does not point a valid video source. A valid video source _may_ look like `http://www.example.com/example.mp4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to make a special code

YouTube give you on every video, a link named share.
under that link you will find another link named embed

for example:  in your question under the link embed
you will find the following code to use it in your page:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zY1vLEk8B9c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

my best wishes

Comment: Tried this. Its still not working. In chrome, the page is just loading. Nothing else, same in the case of Firefox. I cannot see an element.

Comment: Did it. embedded it using the embed tag. Working now.

Comment: so my answer is true ;-)